# Entity framework, same context for MySql and Sqlite

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, entity-framework

Entity framework, same context for MySql and Sqlite

Good afternoon, how are you?

I am developing an app in NET MAUI (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite), and at the same time I have an API (MySQL - Grapemelo.EntityFramework.MySql), both share the same context, I am trying to generate a ModelSnapshot for both MySql annotations as for Sqlite annotations, does anyone know how to do this? I tried everything but it doesn't work...

Here how I configure each one:

FOR NET.MAUI :

Project= StoreSysAppDistribuidorasMigrations.csproj

Command execute= dotnet ef migrations add SqliteInitialCreate -s StoreSysAppDistribuidorasMigrations -p Infrastructure -v --context StoreCustomersContext --output-dir Migrations/SQLiteMigrations

Code=

```
using Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Contexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace StoreSysAppDistribuidorasMigrations;
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}

public class DbContextMigrationFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<StoreCustomersContext>
{
    public StoreCustomersContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreCustomersContext>();
        builder.UseSqlite(ProjectConfig.DatabasePath);
        return new StoreCustomersContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

FOR MySQL:

Project= API_StoreSysBackendCustomers

Command execute= dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s API_StoreSysBackendCustomers -p Infrastructure -v --context StoreCustomersContext --output-dir Migrations/MySqlMigrations

Code=

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Contexts;

namespace API_StoreSysBackendCustomers.Extensions.ContextOptions;

public class StoreCustomersContextOptions : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<StoreCustomersContext>
{
    public StoreCustomersContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreCustomersContext>();
        
        String ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.UseMySql(
            ConnectionString,
             ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString));

        return new StoreCustomersContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Then in my maui program I call Database.Migrate and it appears that it cannot find the database, that is, it cannot create it.

I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You could have two derived DbContext types StoreCustomersContextMySql and StoreCustomersContextSqlLite and configure and migrate them separately.

Comment: The previous comment seems to be a good idea, craete two projects that references your DbContext add two contexts. Also if you are developing an application for Android you have to create e.g. a console app for creating migrations (to set it as startup project) unless this process has been improved since I did this.

Comment: Thank you, your comments helped me, create two contexts that inherit from a base context which has all the data from my database model, and in this way generate the migrations for each context